# React continuous polling

Tags: react.js, timer, typescript, redux

I have a Notifications component in my React app, which continuously polls the server for new notifications. The app uses Redux for storing notifications. When a new notification is received, it is shown on screen. Here's what the code looks like:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

interface ReduxProps {
    notifications: INotification[]
    fetchNotifications: () => any
}

interface IProps extends ReduxProps {}

class NotificationsWidget extends React.Component<IProps> {
    timer: number

    refreshNotifications = () => {
        this.props.fetchNotifications()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = window.setInterval(() => this.refreshNotifications(), 3000)
    }

    render() {
        // ... Show `this.props.notifications`.
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    notifications: state.notifications.items
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchNotifications})(NotificationsWidget)
```

Is this the correct way to go about polling with a React/Redux app? Is there a better way to do polling, or is there an alternative way to push notifications to the browser without polling?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could implement polling but this one is valid enough for a lot of cases.  You could hide your timer off in a redux action somewhere if you were so inclined.

It's worth highlighting that you should clear out your timer when the Component unmounts.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.clearInterval(this.timer)
}
```